# Pattern matching and removal of that pattern using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, string, replace

I have 2 files with the following names:

File 1:  RvA_X-IRB-bil-CA101-0+010000-20150327212332-055582-P

File 2:  RvA_X-IRB-bil-CA101-1+020000-20150327212332-055582-P

I am using this command to match and then replace certain parts of the file names.

```
printf "%s\n" RvA_X-IRB-bil*P | sed -e 's/\(RvA_X-IRB\)-\bil-\(CA.*\)-\0+010000-\([0-9]\{8\}\).*-\([0-9]\{6\}\).*$/mv & \1-\2-\3-\4/'
```

The above mentioned command works fine for the file 1 but when I modify the command to work for the file 2, It doesn't work. The command for the second filename is given below:

```
printf "%s\n" RvA_X-IRB-bil*P | sed -e 's/\(RvA_X-IRB\)-\bil-\(CA.*\)-\1+020000-\([0-9]\{8\}\).*-\([0-9]\{6\}\).*$/mv & \1-\2-\3-\4/'
```

The only thing I have changed is this part `\0+010000-\`

Comment: `\1` is a `back reference` for pattern in first parenthesis. Why you use `\0`,`\1` form instead just `0` or `1`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29369594/1030675

Comment: You can just remove unwanted parts `sed 's/-bil\|-[01]+0[12]0000\|-[^-]*$//g'`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what your final output is supposed to be. You seem to want to rename your files, what are the new names you want to have?

Answer (score 1):

With your regular expression you are recognizing:

"RvA_X-IRB-il-CA101-RvA_X-IRB+020000-20150327212332-055582-P"

in part because you are using \1 as others have pointed out. Note the repeated "RvA_X-IRB".

However, it could be important to note that you are using "\b" as well, and this is going to work only when you do have a "non-word" character in one side and a "word" character in the other. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed

I am not sure if this is intentional, and that is why I ommited the "b" in "-bil". In fact, I am quite surprised that your RE is working in the first case. For example:

```
echo "-bil" | sed 's#-\bil#GETIT#'
-bil

echo "-il" | sed 's#-\bil#GETIT#'
GETIT
```

Or:

```
printf "%s\n" RvA_X-IRB-bil | sed 's/\(RvA_X-IRB\)-\bil/GETIT/'
RvA_X-IRB-bil

printf "%s\n" RvA_X-IRB-il | sed 's/\(RvA_X-IRB\)-\bil/GETIT/'
GETIT
```